# why *start=NULL have to be declare outside braces?Can't we write inside?is there any significance

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have create a node in link list contain two pats .First part contain data (numeric) and second will store address of next node.

```
struct node  
    {  
       int data;  
       struct node *next;  
    }*start=NULL; //why is it to be declare outside braces?
```

Comment: Similar to declaring `struct node *start = NULL`, where `start` is a pointer to type `struct node`

Comment: so it is like  to say that start is a pointer of type struct node ,which can point to a node or store addresse of starting node just like pointer do.we can write below also without declaring adjacent to braces.

Comment: @user3763165: That is correct.

Comment: This is very bad programming style, you should avoid it...

Comment: @iharob :Bad but can do? Also  would it affect ?Or it just affect the readabilty of program

Comment: @user3763165 it would affect a lot of things, because it's declaring a global variable which is almost always a bad idea, specialy if that variable is a pointer intended for dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax

```
struct node  
{  
   int data;  
   struct node *next;  
} *start = NULL; //why is it to be declare outside braces?
```

declares a global variable of type `struct node *`, normally you don't need global variables, except for global library initialization perhaps, and sometimes you can force the user to create a context for the library to work.

I would suggest you keep de `struct` definition and the declaration apart, even if you want to declare a globla variable do it this way

```
struct node  
{  
   int data;  
   struct node *next;  
};
struct node *start;
```

no need to initialize it to `NULL` because that happens automatically for global variables.

As you see, you need to add that part outside the braces because it's a variable declaration, and a much cleaner approach is to split the `struct` defintion from the variable declaration.

I see that a lot of new programmers use global variables to simply use the value in different functions, that's absolutely unnecesary, you could just do this

```
void functionTakingPointerToStruct(struct node *instance)
{
    /* handle instance here */
}

int main()
{
    struct node instance;

    functionTakingPointerToStruct(&instance);
    return 0;
}
```

this way you don't even need dynamic allocation and all the difficulties associated, but you could also use it if you want to

```
int main()
{
    struct node *instance;

    instance = malloc(sizeof(*instance));
    if (instance == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc()");
        reutrn -1;
    }
    functionTakingPointerToStruct(instance);
    return 0;
}
```